# .NET MAUI EntryCompleted Focus

Tags: maui

We are implementing a simple form and validating Entry entered value.
If this value is valid then we do nothing BUT if the value is invalid then we want to keep the focus on the current field and highlight in red. It looks like since the enter key behavior is NEXT that this behavior happens after we set the focus in the completed method???
Is there a way to cancel this?

```
public void control_entry_complete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        bool_result = is_field_value_valid(pattern, value);
        if (!bool_result)
        {
            trx.set_focus(((View)sender).StyleId);
            return;
        //LOOKS LIKE FOCUS IS SET TO NEXT FIELD AFTER THIS RETURN!?!?
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Globals.log.add(ex);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share more code about xaml?

Comment: Also entry has ```ReturnCommand``` property which defines the command to be executed when the return key is pressed.

Comment: This Entry is not created in XAML but dynamically created as a part of a Grid then added to a page.

Comment: It also appears that the return command does not execute when ENTER on hardware keypad is clicked??? I believe this is documented as fixed BUT seems not to be for hardware keyboards!

Comment: Liqun ... your suggestion about the return command looks like it will work! I realize the hardware keyboard does not fire the returncommand but that is a separate issue! When using the softkey board it works (We can control is focus moves or note at this point!

Comment: Okay, that means it doesn't works when using hardware keyboard. Is this issue similar to your question ?  [Entry Return command not firing up - .NET MAUI MVVM on Android](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13921)

Comment: Correct. This sounds exactly like my issue! I have tested this on multiple devices with hardware keypads (Honeywell CK65 and Zebra MC9300) and it consistently does not fire. Looks like your issue mentions another device but again shows consistent behavior for hardware keypads! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You could follow the above issue on Github. If you have solution, you could post an answer here that may help others with same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a logged issue with the Maui project on github BUT there was a good work around posted there as well from Github user bofden per suggestion from Liqun:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13921#issuecomment-1535898241

Thx everybody